# math behind polynomial regression

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-model, scikit-learn

I am creating a polynomial regression  model with Python sci kit learn package, and I was wondering how I can use the `predict` features in machine learning algorithms.

To start with Python scikit-learn I am fitting the model ([shown in my other post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386576/python-scikit-learn-polynomial-regression-coefficients?noredirect=1#comment725983_386576)) and printing rsme & r2 which outputs:

```
2.359112756782707
0.9829246178225791
```

The plotted model is purple:

[image]

If I print the coefficients:

```
print(model.coef_)

print(model.intercept_)
```

I get an array:

```
[[ 0.00000000e+00 -4.17544080e-01  2.87295974e-02 -2.06211620e-04]]
[73.99115377]
```

This may sound like a silly question, but how do I use this to predict values? For example, can I use my model to predict a y value? Would an x value of `40` according to my scatter plot equate to an approximate y value of ~90?

```
Xnew = [[40]]
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)

ynew
```

This gives me an error as I do not understand this concepts of linear algebra/vector.. I think I need a format that matches my `print(model.coef_)` like this below but I don't understand enough to put it to use. Any really basic 101 tips would be greatly appreciated...

```
Xnew = [[...], [...], [...], [...]]
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
```

Comment: The basic of polynomial regression is that before you fit your model, you first add additional variables to your data. These variables are derived from your original data in the following way: If you add quadratic terms to your regression formula, you just square your (numerical) data. If you add a cubic term, you take it to the power of 3 etc... With these new variablse you then fit a normal linear regression.

Comment: Thanks Ill have to do some research on these steps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't apply the polynomial transformation to `Xnew`, so it doesn't have the appropriate size, nor is `Xnew` the polynomial data that you desire.

To fix this, apply  the polynomial transformation to `Xnew`. Here's how that looks:

```
x_new_poly = polynomial_features.transform(Xnew)
model.predict(x_new_poly)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more in your answer, sorry I don't understand.

Comment: What don't you understand? The `model` object has polynomially-transformed data as an input. However, when you call `predict`, you did not transform the input to a polynomial. In other words, `model` doesn't know that you need to transform the data; `model` just expects to receive data of a specific size, and then it does a matrix-vector multiply. End of story. All transformations are incumbent on you.

Comment: That is also what i mean with extra variables (the polynomially transformed data)